# How can I have tapered path in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, path, curve, bezier

I have a Path shape defined in XAML as following :

```
<Path Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="52" x:Name="theCurve">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100" x:Name="curveStartPoint">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <BezierSegment Point1="100,10" Point2="200,200" Point3="300,100" x:Name="curveBezierSegment"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

I want to taper the end of path, check attached image, how can I do that in WPF?
[image]

Comment: I have some code which does roughly that. It's for drawing rivers in our map editor. The user draws a line on an ink canvas. I vary the pressure for each point. High gives a thick line, low thin. It's functionality intended for drawing with a stylus. I then translate to a geometry. You can get the points along your geometry and convert to a point list. Vary the pressure for those points from one end and then get the geometry off the stroke you end up with.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi do you want to control the amount of taper or just want them to be pointy?

Comment: I want to control the amount of taper